# Status bar disappear

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I'm using this library https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift and occasionally when I dismiss the container view or make a segue to another navigation view, I'm losing the status bar... some ideas?

I have on Appdelegate:

```
    application.setStatusBarStyle(.lightContent, animated: true)  
    application.isStatusBarHidden = false
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

and in InfoPlist View controller-based status bar appearance -> NO

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure.just check it out.

In my quick search in that SlideMenuControllerSwift library there is property called `hideStatusBar` from SlideMenuController class it's default value is true. Change it to false & check again.

```
public static var hideStatusBar: Bool = true
```

[Source](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift/blob/master/SlideMenuControllerSwift/UIViewController.swift)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many questions that are similar to yours. You should do some research first before asking a question. However, I'm going to share this class to you that I've been using in my recent projects.

```
import UIKit

public extension UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Status Bar

    /** Status Bar Configuration
     */

    public func showStatusBar() {
        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
    }

    public func hideStatusBar() {
        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
    }

    public func makeStatusBarLight() {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    }

    public func makeStatusBarDark() {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
    }
}
```

**Prerequisite:**

Set this key in your Info.plist

[image: Set this key in your Info.plist]

In your every screen's `viewWillAppear`, call the functions above, whatever you need to toggle. For example:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.showStatusBar()
}
```

EDIT: You may need sometimes to search for an open or closed tickets in your library's repository to find an answer. Or read its documentation. The status bar toggling might most probably caused by the Slide Menu, which most of the similar libraries do.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I try your solution but dosn´t works the problem was with the library ! Thanks anyway!